# @ConditionalOnProperty on TYPE level w/ @Configuration

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on TYPE level so it sees/evaluates properties defined in non-default properties files?

Following seems to work only when the property is defined in the default properties file, i.e. in `application.properties`

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "jmx.rmi", value = "enabled")
public class JmxConfiguration {
    // JMX related stuff
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@ConditionalOnProperty` extracts data from **org.springframework.core.env.Environment** bean. It depends on you how you do populate it. You can explicitly declare multiple properties files:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name = "default", value = "classpath:application.properties"),
        @PropertySource(name = "custom", value = "file:custom.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})
public class SpringBootApplication {...}
```

And the content of both files will be appended to `Environment`

Comment: Could you please explain a bit about these attributes so that it can help in a much more efficient way.