# Spring security configuration: enable/disable authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

my question is like this:

I want to disable and enable authentication through configuration in class which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I have test which expects that status is unauthroized if there is no login info provided. This is configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final String USER = "workshop-user";
    public static final String ADMIN = "workshop-admin";

    @Value("${WORKSHOP_USER_PASSWORD:user}")
    private String userPassword;

    @Value("${WORKSHOP_ADMIN_PASSWORD:admin}")
    private String administratorPassword;

    @Value("${features.security.disable}")
    private boolean securityDisable;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(9);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(USER)
            .password(encoder().encode(userPassword))
            .roles("CLIENT_APP")
            .and()
            .withUser(ADMIN)
            .password(encoder().encode(administratorPassword))
            .roles("CLIENT_APP", "ADMINISTRATOR");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if(!securityDisable) {
            http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/import").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/**/favicon.ico", "/webjars/**", "/api/admin/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                //replace .permitAll() with .authenticated() for authentiaction
                //replace .authenticated() with .permitAll() for disabling security
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        }
        else{
            http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/import").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/**/favicon.ico", "/webjars/**", "/api/admin/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //replace .permitAll() with .authenticated() for authentiaction
                //replace .authenticated() with .permitAll() for disabling security
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        }
    }
```

and this is my flag from application.properties

```
features.security.disable = true
```

I have tried to find another way to do it through configuration but couldn't come to another answer. The thing is that i know it is very simple becaues of if/else statement. One is authenticated and the other permitAll entries. Do you know is there a way that uses "better aproach" which does not pollute code with duplication like this? I tried to look in documentation and other posts but couldn't find any relevant information for me.

Comment: I think for testing purpose excluding the SecurityAutoConfiguration is better than you approach,  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class} )
public class SpringBootTest{}

Comment: One more way is use the separate profiles

Comment: So creating another configure method and using profile on both of them with this flag that I created? Because I want to have option to choose between disabled and enabled security with flag from properties, that is why I don't want to use exclude option.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two security configurations

```
@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/import").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/**/favicon.ico", "/webjars/**", "/api/admin/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                //replace .permitAll() with .authenticated() for authentiaction
                //replace .authenticated() with .permitAll() for disabling security
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}


@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class SecurityConfigTest extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**/import").hasRole("ADMINISTRATOR")
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/**/favicon.ico", "/webjars/**", "/api/admin/health").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                //replace .permitAll() with .authenticated() for authentiaction
                //replace .authenticated() with .permitAll() for disabling security
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().disable()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Run based on your requirement

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

Comment: In addition since the OP asked to toggle the security mechanisms based on a property set within his application properties. You can combine this answer and replace the `@Profile` with `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotations.
To get to know the @ConditionalOnProperty and learn what it is doing have a look at this answer here: [What is purpose of @ConditionalOnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26403131/11133168).

Also always check that your conditions for the @Profiles/ConditionalOnProperty are mutually exclusive or an Order is set!

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion it was very helpful in my research.