# Disabling custom health check endpoints

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

SpringBoot offers a way to disable health check endpoints similar to below

```
management.health.mongo.enabled=false
```

Is there a way to disable a custom health check endpoint which I have created by implementing HealthIndicator interface?

Comment: I am not aware of any healthcheck-specific mechanism here, but what about using @ConditionalOnProperty? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example a mongo health indicator:

Its defined in class: `org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` (see the [source-code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.java))

And looks like a regular configuration with a custom conditional on it:

```
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("mongo")
```

Now this is an internal spring boot actuator's annotation that is basically a custom conditional on property,

Since your custom healthcheck is a bean itself, registering it with this conditional (`@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("whatever")`) will NOT pick your healthcheck as long as there is a property:

```
management.health.whatever.enabled=false
```

If you want the custom property that doesn't follow this standard you can use `@ConditionalOnProperty` as was already suggested by other people here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the code snippet on how you have implemented the custom endpoint?
Maybe `@ConditionalOnProperty` can help as suggested by @Seb. Have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26403131/4875624